# Indirectly changing UI by storing data in a class variable not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

If I want any changes in my UI then I direct pass the data like;

**In HTML Template**

```
<li *ngFor="let post of posts;let i = index;">
  {{i+1}}) {{post.name}}
<button (click)="editCategory(post)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Edit</button>
</li>
```

**In Component TS**

```
editCategory(post){
 post.name="Something";
}
```

this will reflect in the UI too and works fine!

but when I try to do it indirectly that doesn't happen like:

**In HTML Template**

```
 <li *ngFor="let post of posts;let i = index;">
{{i+1}}) {{post.name}}
<button (click)="deleteCategory(post); modal1.show();" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Edit</button>
</li>
<div #modal1="bs-modal">
<button (click)="finallyDeleteCategory(); modal1.show();" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Edit</button> //making changes through this button
</div>
```

**In Component TS**

```
deleteCategory(post){
 this.savedPost=post;
}
finallyDeleteCategory(){
 this.savedPost.name="deleted"; //this Doesn't work
}
```

While am saving data in the class variable then making changes in the variable then it is not reflecting in the UI.

**Doubts:**

1. How can i save the refernce of the Post in the class variable?
2. Is this the correct way to make changes indirectly or i have pass on data in the html itself?

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are changing the status in this.savedPost, but you are iterating on post of posts...that could be why.

Comment: when it works fine, then also `post` is being iterated @Farasi78

Comment: `finallyDeleteCategory(post)` it takes one argument but your function `finallyDeleteCategory()` is different ..  is it correct?

Comment: @Niladri sorry made changes in my question it is not under any iteration it should be  `finallyDeleteCategory()` as it is just a mockup of my scenario.

Comment: not sure what you mean... you are saying:  this.savedPost = post.  this.savedPost.name="deleted", I don't think that changes post.  You would need to set post.name="deleted" for it to show up as deleted.

Comment: @Farasi78 `savedPost` is a class variable that holds clicked `post` data, hope am more clear now!

Comment: So you have ngFor= post of posts, but you are saving changes to savedPosts?  If not, your ngFor should be ngFor post of savedPosts.  Otherwise you need to add another ngFor for savedPosts

Comment: @Farasi78 I know and that is in my doubts and am trying to access `post` indirectly that is soul of the question

Comment: @Farasi78 `modal1` is a pop up not part of the `ngFor` iteration.

Comment: If you want to change post, you have to change post.  Why not pass post to your finallyDeleteCategory?  Is there a reason you want to do it 'indirectly'?

Comment: @Farasi78 how to pass??? it is not part of iteration! can u post an answer?

Comment: @phpdroid `post` is a local variable which exists only in the scope of the *ngFor .. you have to pass it's value as a param to the actual delete function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since finallyDeleteCategory is outside the loop context you cant just pass a reference of post and change its name since it does not exist.

this.savedPost.name="deleted";  does not work because the element being looped are part of the posts array.What you can do is save the post index i  instead of the post object and in the method

```
(click)="editCategory(i)"

deleteCategory(loopindex){
 this.index=loopindex
}
```

finallyDeleteCategory you retrieve the posts from the array then change it directly there.

```
finallyDeleteCategory(){
  posts[this.index].name="deleted";
}
```

Comment: sorry but that doesn't change in UI

Comment: sorry, there was a typo in my code when I followed ur solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you only save the deleted post when you call the 'deleteCategory' method on the list item. So with your setup, the changes will only reflect when you first press the edit button on one of the list items.